# Google Maps: Clickable Overlay with markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to overlay an SVG on Google Maps, and make certain parts of the SVG clickable.
However, I also want it to be possible to place markers on the same map. These should appear on top of the image, and I want a marker click to take priority over a SVG path click.

I have placed an overlay on a Google Map, exactly as described here: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/wjEyMm

This works exactly how I'd want. However, notice that markers go BELOW the image. And yet, clicking the marker through the image executes the click logic of the marker.

```
const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: parseFloat(62.3), lng: parseFloat(-150.22)}
});
marker.addListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Oh hi Marker");
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

Same example with marker added:
https://codepen.io/maikelraow/pen/gOmdmdM

I have tried changing the SVG's layer from **overlayMouseTarget** to **overlayLayer** and while this does put it below the markers, it also prevents any click events from firing on the SVG.

Comment: Could you not use a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple)?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Close, but I'm not sure if there is a way to specifically check what path of the groundoverlay svg was clicked.

Comment: AFAIK `overlayMouseTarget` is the only pane (with the `floatPane`) that will receive DOM events, but it is above the `markerPane`. Have you tried it with a Ground overlay?